# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{tr}}(X)$ a cdh sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology

Suppose $X\in \mathrm{Sm}/k$. Is the sheaf with transfers $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{tr}}(X)$ a cdh sheaf? Its sections are finite correspondences.

Comment: No, it is not: cdh-locally, all finite correspondences are linear combinations of Hilbert cycles (geometric correspondences that are finite and flat on the source).